# Running Karate tests from commandline returns surefire-plugin error

Tags: testing, command-line, cucumber, bdd, karate

I've been trying to run my **.feature** karate files from command line. I've been trying to follow the [docs](https://github.com/intuit/karate#command-line), so that  I've found below instruction:

```
mvn test -Dtest=CatsRunner
```

When I run above command, I see that my tests are running, and all of them are passing. However, there are some errors being popped up at the end of my command line. Below is the log part:

```
1 Scenarios (1 passed)
16 Steps (16 passed)
0m2.388s
Karate version: 0.8.0
html report: (paste into browser to view)
-----------------------------------------
file:/D:/Dev/xxx/yyy/karate/target/surefire-reports/TEST-tvplus.singleuseroperations.authenticate.auth-existing-IPTV-user.html

[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.302 s - in tvplus.singleuseroperations.authenticate.AuthenticateRunner
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.204 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-12T15:50:06+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) on project karate: No tests were executed!  
(Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] 
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I am also pasting my **pom** file below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.xxx.yyy.zzz</groupId>
<artifactId>karate</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.6.0</maven.compiler.version>
    <karate.version>0.8.0</karate.version>
    <jdbc.version>5.1.3.RELEASE</jdbc.version>
    <maven.surefire.version>2.22.1</maven.surefire.version>
</properties>    

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
        <version>${karate.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>            
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>${karate.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${jdbc.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-testng</artifactId>
        <version>${karate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${karate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Also, here is my **CatsRunner.java**:

```
package xyz;

import com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Karate.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:xxx/singleuseroperations/authenticate/auth-existing-user.feature")

public class CatsRunner {
}
```

EDIT: Below part is not related with the question. No need to think about it. Upgrading karate version solved the problem.
I've been using **@CucumberOptions** at the top of my runner class since I've encountered some trouble when adding **@KarateOptions** annotation to my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To eliminate the surefire-plugin error, you may want to add DfailIfNoTests=false to your command line run script. Surefire pluging integrates with the tests you've written. This option will compile and run your tests, but not fail the whole build if some of the tests fail.

Answer (score 0):

The `@KarateOptions` is available only in 0.9.0: https://github.com/intuit/karate/releases/tag/v0.9.0

EDIT: If you simplify your `pom.xml` and avoid using things not needed for Karate you will be able to solve the problem with "surefire-plugin". This is what I have been trying to explain by pointing you to this link: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I've updated my pom file with the 0.9.0 version of the karate. As you've stated, I am now able to use karateoptions. But this update didn't solve my problem, I am still having the surefire-plugin error when I try to run my code over terminal.

Comment: Unfortuntely, my question is not the problem of using karateoptions. Obviously, my question was surefire-plugin error as I stated in the headline. So I didn't upvoted or accepted this answer of yours.

Didn't try the other question's answer yet. Please do not post unrelated things here.